# How can I get my three.js website to switch between scenes

Tags: three.js

I have a three.js site, that has html, first.js, second.js, and a basic main.css.

I want each scene to be entirely different on its own js file (first.js/second.js), and have a new button on each new scene that will be used to go to the next scene of choosing.

The scenes will be different, with different imports, different elements whether three geometries, animations and lighting, to having glb loaders with animations and RGBE background lighting from hdr's, including different lights etc.

I want a simple logic that I can load an entirely new scene, and keeping none of the old scene each time the button is clicked.

At the moment, the console log tells me that the 2 scenes are competing to animate their scene, 1 after the other, but no drastic console errors.

I want to execute this basically, just using three.js, and not other libraries for the time being.

I have tried reading lots of documentation, but can't find anything that seems to work, same with teaching other people's queries.

I have tried adding everything in the scene js files to be wrapped in an export function LoadScene1 (2,3,4 etc) and also functions to load the scene, clear the scene, load new scene, added imports for the new scene etc. At the moment they are similar, for texting purposes.

Here are my files:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        
        <script type="module">
            import * as firstScene from './first.js';
            firstScene.loadScene1();
          </script>
          
    </body>
</html>
```

First.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import { AnimationMixer } from 'three';
import { loadScene2 } from './second.js';


export function loadScene1() {
    let camera1, scene1, renderer1, mixer1, currentModel;
    let isPaused = true;
    let container1;
    let orbitControls;

    const gltfPath = 'models/gltf/VinylCover/glTF/';

    init();
    startAnimation();

    function createButton(text, onClick) {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = text;
        button.style.position = 'absolute';
        button.style.top = '10px';
        button.style.left = '10px';
        button.addEventListener('click', () => onClick());
        return button;
    }
    

    function startAnimation() {
        if (isPaused) {
            isPaused = false;
            mixer1.timeScale = 1;
        } else {
            isPaused = true;
            mixer1.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }

    function init() {
        container1 = document.createElement('container');
        document.body.appendChild(container1);
        console.log('Container element:', container1);

        camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20);
        camera1.position.set(30, 30, 30);
        console.log('Camera Created:', camera1);

        scene1 = new THREE.Scene();

        const hemiLight1 = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 1);
        hemiLight1.color.setHSL(0.6, 1, 0.6);
        hemiLight1.groundColor.setHSL(0.095, 1, 0.75);
        hemiLight1.position.set(0, 50, 0);
        scene1.add(hemiLight1);
        console.log('hemilight created:', container1);

        const dirLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
        dirLight1.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
        dirLight1.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 2);
        dirLight1.position.multiplyScalar(30);
        scene1.add(dirLight1);
        console.log('dirlight created:', container1);

        dirLight1.castShadow = true;
        dirLight1.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        dirLight1.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

        const d = 50;
        dirLight1.shadow.camera.left = -d;
        dirLight1.shadow.camera.right = d;
        dirLight1.shadow.camera.top = d;
        dirLight1.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
        dirLight1.shadow.camera.far = 3500;
        dirLight1.shadow.bias = -0.0001;

        new RGBELoader()
            .setPath('textures/equirectangular/')
            .load('sky14k.hdr', function (texture) {
                texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
                scene1.background = texture;
                scene1.environment = texture;

                loadModel();
            });

        renderer1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer1.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer1.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer1.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
        renderer1.toneMappingExposure = 1;
        container1.appendChild(renderer1.domElement);
        console.log('Renderer Created:', container1);

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

        orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera1, renderer1.domElement);
        orbitControls.minDistance = 2;
        orbitControls.maxDistance = 10;
        orbitControls.target.set(0, 0, -0.2);
        orbitControls.update();

        mixer1 = new AnimationMixer();

        const loadnextScene1Button = createButton('Next Scene', () => clearScene({ scene: scene1, mixer: mixer1, orbitControls: orbitControls, currentModel: currentModel }));
        document.body.appendChild(loadnextScene1Button);
        console.log('Button Created:', loadnextScene1Button);

        animate({
            scene: scene1,
            mixer: mixer1,
            orbitControls: orbitControls,
            isPaused: isPaused,
        });
    }

    function loadModel() {
        console.log('Loading GLB model:', loadModel);
        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/draco/');
        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

        const loader = gltfLoader.setPath(gltfPath);

        loader.load('VinylCover.glb', function (gltf) {
            console.log('Model loaded successfully:', gltf);

            const newModel = gltf.scene;
            scene1.add(newModel);
            newModel.position.y = -1;

            mixer1 = new AnimationMixer(newModel);
            currentModel = newModel; // Set currentModel here

            if (gltf.animations && gltf.animations.length > 0) {
                const allActions = gltf.animations.map(clip => mixer1.clipAction(clip));
                allActions.forEach((action) => {
                    action.play();
                });

                isPaused = false;
            }

            orbitControls.enabled = true;

            console.log('New model added to the scene.');
            console.log(scene1);
        },
        null,
        (error) => {
            console.error('An error occurred while loading the model:', error);
        });
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
        if (mixer1) {
            mixer1.update(0.01);
        }
    
        if (!isPaused) {
            render();
        }
    
        if (orbitControls.enabled) {
            orbitControls.update();
        }
    
        console.log('Animating first scene');
    }
    

    function render() {
        if (renderer1) {
            renderer1.render(scene1, camera1);
        }
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
        camera1.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera1.updateProjectionMatrix();

        if (renderer1) {
            renderer1.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }
        render();
    }
    function clearScene(scene) {
        // Stop and clear the animations
        if (scene.mixer) {
            scene.mixer.stopAllAction();
            scene.mixer.uncacheAction(scene.currentModel);
            scene.mixer = null;
        }
    
        // Remove the current model from the scene
        if (scene.currentModel) {
            scene.currentModel.traverse((obj) => {
                if (obj.isMesh) {
                    obj.geometry.dispose();
                    obj.material.dispose();
                }
            });
    
            scene.scene.remove(scene.currentModel);
            scene.currentModel = null;
        }
    
        // Dispose renderer resources
        if (scene.renderer) {
            scene.renderer.dispose();
        }
    
        // Clear the scene
        scene.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
        // Re-initialize other components as needed
        init(scene);
    
        // Load the next scene
        loadScene2();
    }
    
    
    
    
    


}
```

Second.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import { AnimationMixer } from 'three';
import { loadScene3 } from './third.js';

export function loadScene2() {
    let camera2, scene2, renderer2, mixer2, currentModel2;
    let isPaused = true;
    let container2;
    let orbitControls2;

    const gltfPath = 'models/gltf/VinylCover/glTF/';

    init2();
    animate2();
    startAnimation2();

    function createButton2(text, onClick) {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = text;
        button.style.position = 'absolute';
        button.style.top = '10px';
        button.style.left = '10px';
        button.addEventListener('click', onClick);
        return button;
    }

    function startAnimation2() {
        if (isPaused) {
            isPaused = false;
            mixer2.timeScale = 1;
        } else {
            isPaused = true;
            mixer2.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }

    function init2() {
        container2 = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container2);
        console.log('Container element:', container2);

        camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20);
        camera2.position.set(30, 30, 30);
        console.log('Camera Created:', camera2);

        scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

        const hemiLight2 = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 1);
        hemiLight2.color.setHSL(0.6, 1, 0.6);
        hemiLight2.groundColor.setHSL(0.095, 1, 0.75);
        hemiLight2.position.set(0, 50, 0);
        scene2.add(hemiLight2);
        console.log('hemilight created:', container2);

        const dirLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
        dirLight2.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
        dirLight2.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 2);
        dirLight2.position.multiplyScalar(30);
        scene2.add(dirLight2);
        console.log('dirlight created:', container2);

        dirLight2.castShadow = true;
        dirLight2.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        dirLight2.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

        const d = 50;
        dirLight2.shadow.camera.left = -d;
        dirLight2.shadow.camera.right = d;
        dirLight2.shadow.camera.top = d;
        dirLight2.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
        dirLight2.shadow.camera.far = 3500;
        dirLight2.shadow.bias = -0.0001;

        new RGBELoader()
            .setPath('textures/equirectangular/')
            .load('sky14k.hdr', function (texture) {
                texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
                scene2.background = texture;
                scene2.environment = texture;

                loadModel2();

                animate2({
                    scene: scene2,
                    mixer: mixer2,
                    orbitControls: orbitControls2,
                    isPaused: isPaused,
                });
            });

        renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer2.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer2.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
        renderer2.toneMappingExposure = 1;
        container2.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);
        console.log('Renderer Created:', container2);

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

        orbitControls2 = new OrbitControls(camera2, renderer2.domElement);
        orbitControls2.minDistance = 2;
        orbitControls2.maxDistance = 10;
        orbitControls2.target.set(0, 0, -0.2);
        orbitControls2.update();

        mixer2 = new AnimationMixer();

        const loadnextScene2Button = createButton2('Next Scene', () => clearScene2({ scene: scene2, mixer: mixer2, orbitControls: orbitControls2, currentModel: currentModel2 }));
    document.body.appendChild(loadnextScene2Button);
    console.log('Button Created:', loadnextScene2Button);
    }

    function loadModel2() {
        console.log('Loading GLB model:', loadModel2);
        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/draco/');
        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

        const loader = gltfLoader.setPath(gltfPath);

        loader.load('CellFragment.glb', function (gltf) {
            console.log('Model loaded successfully:', gltf);

            const newModel = gltf.scene;
            scene2.add(newModel);
            newModel.position.y = -1;

            mixer2 = new AnimationMixer(newModel);

            if (gltf.animations && gltf.animations.length > 0) {
                const allActions = gltf.animations.map(clip => mixer2.clipAction(clip));
                allActions.forEach((action) => {
                    action.play();
                });

                isPaused = false;
            }

            orbitControls2.enabled = true;

            console.log('New model added to the scene.');
            console.log(scene2);
        },
        null,
        (error) => {
            console.error('An error occurred while loading the model:', error);
        });
    }

    function animate2() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate2);

        if (mixer2) {
            mixer2.update(0.01);
        }

        if (!isPaused) {
            render2();
        }

        if (orbitControls2.enabled) {
            orbitControls2.update();
        }

        console.log('Animating second scene');
    }

    function render2() {
        if (renderer2) {
            renderer2.render(scene2, camera2);
        }
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
        camera2.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();

        if (renderer2) {
            renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }
        render2();
    }

    function clearScene2() {
        // Stop and clear the animations
        if (mixer2) {
            mixer2.stopAllAction();
            mixer2.uncacheAction(currentModel2);
            mixer2 = null;
        }
    
        // Remove the current model from the scene
        if (currentModel2) {
            currentModel2.traverse((obj) => {
                if (obj.isMesh) {
                    obj.geometry.dispose();
                    obj.material.dispose();
                }
            });
    
            scene2.remove(currentModel2);
            currentModel2 = null;
        }
    
        // Dispose renderer resources
        if (renderer2) {
            renderer2.dispose();
        }
    
        // Clear the scene
        scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
    
        // Re-initialize other components as needed
        initScene2();
    
        // Load the next scene
        loadScene3();
    }
    
}
```